# How to remove Stopwords using %in% operator

Tags: r

I have a list of words in a dataset .

My question: Any idea how to fix the following code?

```r
new_words <- c("it", "apple", "carrot", "after",
 "snake")
# My first solution
removeWords(new_words,
 words = stopwords (kind = "en")
# I have a problem in the Second solution,
# because I want to use #%in% operator
new_words[new_words %in%
 words = stopwords(kind = "en")]
```

Comment: Remove the `words = ` part and try again.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I did my best to organize my question very well. How did you fix it? Sorry first time asking a question on this website

Comment: Yes, I tried that code in that way as well, it did not work out

Comment: @Eljan, for formatting codes and questions, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189 and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: @Eljan In this case please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please check the question again, I tried to describe the question, if you have any question please let me know

Comment: `new_words[!new_words %in% stopwords::stopwords()]` should work.

Comment: @Martin, I would like to follow this solution to understand. I have a dataset with over 10000 words. How can I remove the stopwords using your solution? This code did not work in my side

Comment: To be clear, it works but when I apply it for another dataset, which has over 10000 words, it does not work

Comment: Your other dataset... is it also a character vector like your example or are you using some other structure like a data.frame?

Comment: So, my project is basically to scan the reviews in the website and find out top frequent words. I have scanned the webpage and I have a lot of words. It is not a character vector. Now, I am trying to remove the stopwords.

Comment: To answer your question it is necessary and important to know the structure of your data. The suggestion works for a character vector but will fail for a data.frame without small adjustments.

Comment: Thank you, I finally figured out. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

why not just `anti_join(stop_words)`?

that's how Julia Silge does it in Text Mining for R... https://www.tidytextmining.com/index.html